# JQuery event hooked multiple times

Tags: c#-4.0

I've a page contains Ajax UpdatePanel and has some controls inside of it, and some other controls outside of it, when I click on a submit button the UpdatePanel will be updated and the JQuery events will re-hooked by using "Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();" as the code below:

```
function DocReady() {
    $('#txtNewPassword').click(function () {
        alert('clicked');
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
     DocReady();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        DocReady();
    });
});
```

The problem is, after any partial postback the controls outside the UpdatePanel JQuery events re-hooked X times where X = number of partial postback calls.

Comment: why $(document).ready repeat ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove all click events before you set the new one.

```
function DocReady() {
    $('#txtNewPassword').unbind('click');
    $('#txtNewPassword').click(function () {
        alert('clicked');
    });
}
```

It's not the cleanest of code but it seems like you're just adding a new click event to the textbox each time so this way would remove any previous events and then add the new one.